# Checking status of subscription using Play Billing Library

Tags: android

In my app I have subscriptions. I implemented a purchase flow and check for subscriptions status using classic way using IInAppBillingService. I got some problems using this way. Around 1% users complain that after a successful purchasing of a subscription these subscriptions do not work within the app. I asked the support of Google Pla for this problem. They recommended using a new Play Billing Library. I looked at the example in the instructions https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/play-billing-codelab/#6. However, this example does not consider checking the status of the subscription.

Also I found on the page https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html following: "The Google Play service returns the purchases made by the user account logged in to the device. If the request is successful, the Play Billing Library stores the query results in a List of Purchase objects. To retrieve the list, call the getPurchasesList() method on the PurchasesResult object."

So to BillingManager class from tutorial I added a code to check purchases for subscriptions:

```
public Purchase.PurchasesResult querySubscriptionPurchases() {
        return mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
    }
```

Using BillingManager in the MainActivity:

```
mBillingManager = new BillingManager(this);
        Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingManager.querySubscriptionPurchases();
        if (purchasesResult != null) {
            List<Purchase> p = purchasesResult.getPurchasesList();
        }
```

When I run app, in the logcat I see "I/BillingManager: onBillingSetupFinished() response: 0". So connection is successful?

But purchasesResult is null and I can't get a list of purchases to explore what this list contains to get SKUs of active subscriptions. In the debug mode classic way using IInAppBillingService returns purchases successfully, I have one active subscription for test and it works.

Full listing of BillingManager:

```
public class BillingManager implements PurchasesUpdatedListener {
    private static final String TAG = "BillingManager";

    private final BillingClient mBillingClient;
    private final Activity mActivity;

    private static final HashMap<String, List<String>> SKUS;
    static
    {
        SKUS = new HashMap<>();
        SKUS.put(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS, Arrays.asList("no_ads", "sub2", "sub3"));
    }

    public BillingManager(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(mActivity).setListener(this).build();
        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponse) {
                if (billingResponse == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() response: " + billingResponse);
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() error code: " + billingResponse);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                Log.w(TAG, "onBillingServiceDisconnected()");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int responseCode,
                                   List<Purchase> purchases) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPurchasesUpdated() response: " + responseCode);
    }

    public List<String> getSkus(@BillingClient.SkuType String type) {
        return SKUS.get(type);
    }

    private void startServiceConnectionIfNeeded(final Runnable executeOnSuccess) {
        if (mBillingClient.isReady()) {
            if (executeOnSuccess != null) {
                executeOnSuccess.run();
            }
        } else {
            mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponse) {
                    if (billingResponse == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() response: " + billingResponse);
                        if (executeOnSuccess != null) {
                            executeOnSuccess.run();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() error code: " + billingResponse);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onBillingServiceDisconnected()");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public Purchase.PurchasesResult querySubscriptionPurchases() {
        return mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
    }

    public void querySkuDetailsAsync(@BillingClient.SkuType final String itemType,
                                     final List<String> skuList, final SkuDetailsResponseListener listener) {
        // Specify a runnable to start when connection to Billing client is established
        Runnable executeOnConnectedService = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SkuDetailsParams skuDetailsParams = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                        .setSkusList(skuList).setType(itemType).build();
                mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParams,
                        new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode,
                                                             List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                                listener.onSkuDetailsResponse(responseCode, skuDetailsList);
                            }
                        });
            }
        };

        // If Billing client was disconnected, we retry 1 time and if success, execute the query
        startServiceConnectionIfNeeded(executeOnConnectedService);
    }

    public void startPurchaseFlow(final String skuId, final String billingType) {
        // Specify a runnable to start when connection to Billing client is established
        Runnable executeOnConnectedService = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                        .setType(billingType)
                        .setSku(skuId)
                        .build();
                mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(mActivity, billingFlowParams);
            }
        };

        // If Billing client was disconnected, we retry 1 time and if success, execute the query
        startServiceConnectionIfNeeded(executeOnConnectedService);
    }

    public void destroy() {
        mBillingClient.endConnection();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a code from TrivialDrive example. Now it works.

in the MainActivity:

```
mUpdateListener = new myBillingUpdateListener();
        mBillingManager = new BillingManager(this, getUpdateListener());
```

and

```
@Override
        public void onPurchasesUpdated(List<Purchase> purchaseList) {

            for (Purchase purchase : purchaseList) {
                switch (purchase.getSku()) {
                    case "no_ad":
                        doNotShowAds = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

in the BillingManager:

```
@Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(int resultCode, List<Purchase> purchases) {
        if (resultCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
            for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                handlePurchase(purchase);
            }
            mBillingUpdatesListener.onPurchasesUpdated(mPurchases);
        } else if (resultCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.USER_CANCELED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPurchasesUpdated() - user cancelled the purchase flow - skipping");
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onPurchasesUpdated() got unknown resultCode: " + resultCode);
        }
    }
```